# Write to Excel using VB (many lines)

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

My code creates an Excel file successfully from a query in SQL although it takes too much time to create it.How can I minimize the time to create it?
The code is the following :

```
rsAnaforaPr.DoQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[zam_excel]")
rsAnaforaPr.MoveFirst()
   hj = False
   rowCount = 1
   While rsAnaforaPr.EoF = False
        shell1 = rsAnaforaPr.Fields.Item("Value1").Value
        If hj = False Then
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
            hj = True
            oBook.SaveAs("C:\Desktop\New folder\excel.xlsx")
            oBook.Close(True)
            oExcel.Quit()
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\New folder\excel.xlsx")        
            oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            oSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).Value = "Value1"
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            oSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).NumberFormat = "@"
            oSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).Value = shell1 
       Else
            oSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).NumberFormat = "@"
            oSheet.Range("A" & rowCount).Value = shell1                     
        End If
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        rsAnaforaPr.MoveNext()
    End While
    oBook.Close(True)
    oExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: If you build a 2D array inside your while loop and write the array to the spreadsheet it will fill it much faster. Just write the array to the top-left cell of where you want the data, and it will write everything all at once instead of cell by cell

Comment: First read all from the recordset in a loop. Record the elements in an array. Then write it all to a single range in Excel.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Code Review](http://stackexchange.codereview.com) IMO.

Comment: Remember, you can grab an array of the entire recordset with `GetRows` method (both `DAO` and `ADO` libs supports it) and populate after that an one-cell-range, that's represent upper left corner, with that array.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following at the beginning:

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Then at the end of your code write:

`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

The speed upgrade will be visible & noticeable. 
Read more about the `ScreenUpdating` property here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-screenupdating-property-excel

Comment: Hello Vityata ,when i write this i received the error Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

I use code similar to the below.
But, saying that, I've just noticed your `VB.NET` tag... read it as Access for some reason.
I guess this wouldn't work for that?  Someone let me know & I'll delete the answer.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo -1
        On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE
        Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    Set oWrkBk = oXL.workbooks.Add

    oXL.Visible = True

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = DB.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[zam_excel]")
    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
    Next prm
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        oWrkBk.worksheets(1).range("A1").CopyFromRecordSet rst
    End If

EXIT_PROC:

        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        Select Case Err.Number

            Case Else
                MsgBox Err.Description & "( " & Err.Number & ")", vbOKOnly
                Resume EXIT_PROC
        End Select

End Sub
```